# The requested URL /how-do-i-find-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-jquery was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have sub-domain like`demos.testing.com` and i would like to get my url like

> demos.testing.com/how-do-i-find-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-jquery

I have `index.php` file in `demos.testing.com` root folder and i reading the first parameter as

```
$request_uri = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 1);
```

When i request site like : `demos.testing.com/how-do-i-find-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-jquery` it is giving following error :

The requested URL `/how-do-i-find-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-jquery` was not found on this server.

Please tell me how can rewrite url in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist. So you need to use `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` to rewrite to `index.php`. Have you not tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` is an Apache specific configuration file, and more over depending on your main Apache configuration, it may or may not even be parsed. To get an answer, you need to properly tell us what Web server you are using (is it Apache? If not .htaccess won't work and you need to write your rewrite rules in some other Web-server specific way). If Apache, do you have AllowOverride set?

Assuming all of this is true (you use Apache and it is set to read .htaccess), try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This basically rewrites everything which is *not* a real existing file or directory to `index.php`.

As I said, depending on your setup, this may not work. If it doesn't, please tell us more about your setup (which server, what PHP SAPI, etc.).

Comment: That's perfect. Your assumption was true. It working for me. Thanks.